# convert fuerte package to groovy

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I found a line-following package (https://github.com/robotictang/eddiebot_line_follower) that was originally made for fuerte, and I would like to use it groovy. The rosmake compilation generates errors probably due to the incompatibilities between groovy and fuerte. What can I do, is there any description or tutorial that helps to convert between the different ROS versions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59853/convert-fuerte-package-to-groovy/) by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 248 on 2013-04-03

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [freadx](https://answers.ros.org/users/4069/freadx/) on 2013-04-03**:
I guess ROS Packages are not forward compatible.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2013-04-03**:
I don't think that is quite a fair assertion.  Most ROS packages work on multiple versions with no changes.  I'm unsure exactly what error @ZoltanS is encountering, but looking into the new catkin build tools would be a good place to start.  The eddiebot package doesn't even have a `package.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In this case, the issue is that `eddiebot_line_follower` uses `CvBridge.h`, which was marked as deprecated in [fuerte](http://ros.org/doc/fuerte/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/classsensor__msgs_1_1CvBridge.html) and removed in [groovy](http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/cv_bridge/html/c++/files.html).

To get the package to work in groovy, you'll need to update `eddiebot_line_follower` to work with the current cv_bridge API.  The following changes get the code to compile on my machine (under groovy):

```
 40 //#include <cv_bridge/CvBridge.h>

103 cv::Mat imgMat = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg, "rgb8")->image;
104 IplImage* img = new IplImage(imgMat);

238 cv_bridge::CvImage tmpImg(std_msgs::Header(), "rgb8", cv::Mat(img));
239 sensor_msgs::ImagePtr out = tmpImg.toImageMsg();
```

*NOTE: this trivial mod introduces a small memory leak (IplImage header).  You should add the appropriate de-allocation call later to release the memory, if you intend to use this for anything other than testing purposes*

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-04-05**:
Hi Jeremy, thanks it worked! Finally, it can be compiled.